# How can i set up my SSH tunnel connection for run http request from local PC

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, putty, tunnel

My remote server have access to specific third party API. But my local PC doesn't. I can do third party http request from server nodejs backend:

```
await axios.post("http://111.111.111.111:8810")
```

How can i setup SSH connection with tunneling for doing the similar request from my local PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOCKS is the usual and most flexible method – your SSH client can pretend to be a SOCKS proxy, and Axios appears to support using a SOCKS proxy with help of a separate module.

Enable the "SOCKS proxy" by adding a "Dynamic" tunnel within PuTTY's SSH>Tunnel settings. (Alternatively, for both `ssh.exe` and `plink.exe`, use the `-D` option.) Test it out with `curl -x` first – some SSH servers might be configured to disable tunnels.

Here's a [random article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-a-socks-proxy-in-axios-6c0355a2e013) I found about configuring Axios – while it talks about Tor, everything applies to any other kind of SOCKS server:

```javascript
import { SocksProxyAgent } from "socks-proxy-agent";

const agent = new SocksProxyAgent("socks://127.0.0.1:9050");
```